# Why does the Datediff function show different values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I am executing following query I am getting different results.

```
SELECT Datediff(year, 0, Getdate());
```

**The result was 115**

When I use this, I am getting another result:

```
SELECT Datediff(year, 1900, Getdate());
```

**The result was 110**

Actually in SQL Server it will take from `1900-01-01`, but why do these show different values?

Comment: if you change 1900 to '1900' you will get the same result as your first example - '1900' will be internally cast as 1900-01-01

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this to explain the logic:

```
select cast(0 as datetime)
select cast(1 as datetime)
```

An integer is interpreted as the number of Days since 1900-01-01 whereas a string value such as '1900' will be interpreted as a date format.

1900 Days from Jan 1st 1900 is 1905-03-16, which is five years from 1900 and 110 years from now (2015).

Answer (score 15):

This is because if you cast 0 as datetime, it returns 1900 as the year part, whereas 1900 cast as datetime returns 1905 as the year part.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ICGY32404)

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(v=sql.80).aspx):

> Values with the datetime data type are stored internally by Microsoft SQL Server as two 4-byte integers. The first 4 bytes store the number of days before or after the base date, January 1, 1900. The base date is the system reference date.

That means, casting the literal 0 to `datetime` is equivalent to getting the datetime value for 0 days after 1/1/1900, which is 1/1/1900. Similarly for 1900. Therefore, as @MartinSmith points out in the comments, your calculation is equivalent to `SELECT Datediff(year,dateadd(d,0,'1/1/1900'), Getdate())` which returns 115 as expected.

Possibly worth noting that the MSDN page on Cast and Convert does not specifically cover this scenario i.e. `int` to `datetime`.

Comment: Missing explanation that casting an int to datetime effectively works the same as `DATEADD(DAY` to `1900-01-01`

Comment: @MartinSmith Agreed. Trying to hunt down from MSDN if there is anything specific about the 0 value. Can you please point me to it?

Comment: Can't see this mentioned in the `CAST` topic. The the base date of January 1, 1900 for the binary representation is mentioned here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, that's my problem also, which is why I haven't updated the answer. Perhaps you might want to add your answer too?

Comment: Right, but bad explanation. 1900 (without quotes) means *1900 days since 1900-01-01*.

Answer (score 3):

The number you specified will be added as days which resulted in the difference.

```
Select DATEADD(dd,0,0)
Select DATEADD(dd,1900,0)
```

Result1 is 1900
Result2 is 1905.

So using them is equal to:

```
SELECT Datediff(year,0, Getdate()) = SELECT Datediff(year,DATEADD(dd,0,0), Getdate());

SELECT Datediff(year,1900, Getdate()) = SELECT Datediff(year,DATEADD(dd,1900,0), Getdate());;
```